# Default parameter value in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to set a default, initial, value for a parameter in Tableau? Moreover, is i possible to have this contingent on the value of another parameter or dimension?

So for instance, having two time-series A and B with the same measures/dimensions etc., I would like to scale a specific measure within these using the above mentioned parameter. The initial scaling value, however, is supposed to be different depending on time-series A or B.

Any thoughts here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Parameters support a default/initial value. It is called 'current value' in the 'Create Parameter' window.

[image]

2. Parameter values can be changed only using user interaction. It's value cannot be changed using another parameter or dimension, but you can restrict the allowed values based on a dimension.
3. Above restriction is generally not an issue as you can create calculated fields that depends on other parameters or dimensions. This should be applicable in your case as well, but impossible to be sure without a data set sample.

Comment: So for point 2: this is what I would like. That if a dimension value is 'A', the parameter "default value" would be set to say 10 whereas if the dimension value is 'B' it should be set to 20. Currently I can only set the initial value once, and that's it. It can't be variable which is very annoying